# Help sending email usings the linux mail command in a perl CGI script

Tags: perl, email, command-line, cgi

How can I send an html email using the linux command line inside of a perl CGI script. 
I tried:

```
system(echo $message | mail -s $subject $email);
```

Comment: Depending on the application, system, environment, etc, you may want to look at the various modules in the Email:: and Mail:: namespace as an alternative way of sending mail from webservers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl is not shell. What you are doing here is calling some Perl subroutine with the "bare word" `echo` and passing the value of `$message` binary or-ed with the output of some sub called `mail` which is passed the size of the file named in `$subject` (`-s` operator)--and we can only get this far after completely ignoring that it wouldn't even compile because there is no operator between `$email` and the expression before it.

In Perl, you need quotes for your system commands. But because `$message` could have any number of characters that would make it hard to pass as-is to a shell, it's best to open a pipe and print to it:

```
use English qw<$OS_ERROR>;

open( my $mailh, '|-', "mail -s '$subject' $email" )
    or die( "Could not open pipe! $OS_ERROR" )
    ;
print $mailh $message;
close $mailh;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egbarr/libnet-1.22/Net/SMTP.pm).

From the documentation:

> This module implements a client interface to the SMTP and ESMTP protocol, enabling a perl5 application to talk to SMTP servers.
>
> ...
>
> This example sends a small message to the postmaster at the SMTP server known as mailhost:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use Net::SMTP;

$smtp = Net::SMTP->new('mailhost');

$smtp->mail($ENV{USER});
$smtp->to('postmaster');

$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: postmaster\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("A simple test message\n");
$smtp->dataend();

$smtp->quit;
```